Field Service Lightning Cant get Appointment or Candidate due to being unable to find scheduling policy
I have enabled FSL, Installed the managed package and done the guided setup where all of the records for scheduling policies, territories, etc. were created.  I have assigned the correct permissions to the users and have double checked all of these values.  However I am unable to get appointments or assign resources to a work order and I keep getting this following error: We couldn't complete the Get Candidates action because there's no default Scheduling Policy. Define a default and make sure that you have the required sharing access level. Then, try again
I have created the policy and added rules to it.  I have set it as default in the Dispatch Console UI.  I have double checked user permissions to ensure they have access to it.  I have unset the default and reset it.  I have recreated the policy and yet I keep getting the same error and I don't understand why.  I have searched for answers everywhere in the documentation on I can't find anything that could point me in the right direction.  Does anyone here know what could be the problem?
